# Using Derived Table to get count of records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using Access 2016. I want to get the last records in a table based on the unique record count in another table The following query works:

```
SELECT TOP 3 tblMilestone.MilestoneAbbr, tblMilestone.ID
FROM tblMilestone
ORDER BY tblMilestone.ID DESC;
```

but when I replace the number `3` with the following I get an error `The select statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or is missing, or the punctuation is incorrect`:

```
SELECT Count(dt.MilestoneAbbr) AS MilestoneAbbr
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT tblStandardWork.MilestoneAbbr
FROM tblStandardWork)  AS dt;
```

Both queries work independently. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Here is the entire query:

```
SELECT TOP (SELECT Count(dt.MilestoneAbbr) AS MilestoneAbbr
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT tblStandardWork.MilestoneAbbr
FROM tblStandardWork)  AS dt;)
tblMilestone.MilestoneAbbr, tblMilestone.ID
FROM tblMilestone
ORDER BY tblMilestone.ID DESC;
```

Comment: Sow the entire query that is generating the error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi Gordon! I edited my question to include the entire query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware (and I'll happily be proven wrong), MS Access will only allow a constant to follow the `TOP` operator in a SQL statement.

Therefore, you may need to construct your SQL statement on-the-fly using VBA.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you are correct. In Access SQL the `TOP` keyword must be followed by a numeric literal. It can either be an integer value (e.g., `TOP 5`) or a percentage (e.g., `TOP 10%`).

Comment: @Lee Mac I think that's probably accurate. I think I'll do what you suggest, set a variable equal to the second query and use it in my top statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but not as a query alone. Write VBA that takes the result of the subquery and inserts it into the final query then runs it.  That way your final query is only putting a numeric literal following the TOP keyword, but you are deriving that numeric literal from the other query.